# passing integer values to cookies in jsp

Tags: java, servlets

I have an integer value in my java servlet code which is being retrieved from the database and i need to add that value to a cookie.

```
int k=rs.getInt(3);
Cookie c1= new Cookie("access", k);
```

But this line throws an error saying:

```
Cookie c1= new Cookie("access", k);
             ^
required: String,String
found: String,int
reason: actual argument int cannot be converted to String by method invocation
conversion
1 error
```

I understand the error but how do I go about passing a int value to a cookie. I am new to servlets. Your help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the documentation of [Cookie](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#Cookie%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), the only constructor it has takes both the argument as `String`. So, you need to convert your `integer` value to a `String`.

You can use `String.valueOf(int)` method for that: -

```
int k=rs.getInt(3);
Cookie c1 = new Cookie("access", String.valueOf(k));
```

Comment: request parameters, cookies, headers all should be strings

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Cookie c1= new Cookie("access", "" + k);
```